# mysql_select_db fail on somepage

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a social website for my company. The problem appears only in "diary" page. Most of time, my code connects to database successful, but sometime, it throws error:

> `Could not select database`

This is my php code to connect to database on localhost:

```
function execute_action($query)
 {
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123456")  or 
                                               die("Could not connect");
    mysql_select_db("2t") or die("Could not select database");

    $query = $query;
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed");

    return $result ;

}
```

Do you have any solution to help me. Thanks for reading.

Comment: You dont need to connect to database for each and every query you are executing. Make one connection for a session.

Comment: Neither you are passing the link to your mysql_select_db.

Comment: What does [`mysql_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) say?

Answer (score 1):

As you arent closing your database connections between querys, so, my first thought would be is you're reaching a max connection barrier to the mySQL server.

While this may not be the answer - showing the mysql_error would help.

As someone else pointed out, theres no need to connect and drop each time. Unless your page has incredibly long processing time, connecting at the start, closing at the end should be enough.

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the dbconfiguration $link while selecting the db and executing the query

```
mysql_select_db("2t", $link)
```

even in `mysql_query( $query, $link)`

Comment: That is not what the [docs say](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php).

Comment: doc says `The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed.`

Comment: In the case of his code, the last link opened is in the line immediately before `mysql_select_db`.